# Hide parent if great, great, great, great grandchild is empty

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So, I'm using Beaver Builder on a site, and ACF to add a video module. However, not every page may have a video, but if the video isn't added in the page, the containing div.fl-row is still showing. I've added a function to hide the video module, but the rest of the html is still showing.

**PHP to hide empty module:**

```
function check_field_connections($is_visible, $node) {

    if (isset($node->settings->connections)) {
        foreach ($node->settings->connections as $key => $connection) {
            if (!empty($connection) && empty($node->settings->$key)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $is_visible;

}

add_filter( 'fl_builder_is_node_visible', 'check_field_connections', 10, 2 );
```

**fl.row with no ACF module (note the .fl-node-content with breaks)**

```
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-59f4de2e0191e" data-node="59f4de2e0191e">
    <div class="fl-row-content-wrap">
        <div class="fl-row-content fl-row-fixed-width fl-node-content">
            <div class="fl-col-group fl-node-59f4de2e0667c" data-node="59f4de2e0667c">
                <div class="fl-col fl-node-59f4de2e067c6" data-node="59f4de2e067c6">
                    <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I hide that .fl-row? Thanks!

Comment: I would assign an id at the point i want to remove further up the chain 
As long as you can make the link between the video and the id you can easily remove the grt grt grt grt grt grt grandpapa along with all its relatives.

Comment: What about something like... $(.fl-row .fl-node-content).each(function() 
    if ($(this).children().length == 0)
        {$(this).closest(".fl-row").hide();
    }
});

Comment: Seem like that would do the trick. although i think that might still leave it in the document, try remove instead of hide (if its not needed at all and wont be).

Comment: If it works for you, answer your own question and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.fl-row .fl-node-content').each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length == 0){
        $(this).closest('.fl-row').hide();
    }
});
```